# VBA to copy data and insert rows based on criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a task wherein I get calendar for a individual in a specific format as below:

Sheet1
Column A - Date
Column B - Location
Column C - Departure Date (in text format 10-Jan-2017 10:00 AM)
Column D - Arrival Date (in text format 10-Jan-2017 10:00 AM)
Column E - New Location
Column F - Notes

The tasks I need to perform are as below:

1. Copy Sheet1 data to Sheet2
2. While copying data, I need to insert rows based on the below criteria

If Column C Departure Date and Column D Arrival Date is on the same day, then insert a new row with values as below:

Column A - Same date as per the row above
Column B - New Location from Column E as per the row above
Column C - BLANK
column D - BLANK
Column E - BLANK
Column F - BLANK

If Column C Departure Date and Column D Arrival Date are different dates, then no need to insert rows, follow same sequence as data from Sheet1.

I used the below code, but facing 2 issues as mentioned below:

-This code only works on Sheet1. Can you help me add this to Sheet2, so I can have Sheet1 with the original data and Sheet2 with the results I need?
- Also, the below code uses a text "INSERT" as the criteria. I want to change this to read Column C and Column D and if the dates are same, then add a new row below the date. (PLEASE REMEMBER THAT COLUMN C AND COLUMN D HAVE DATES IN TEXT FORMAT SO WE MAY HAVE TO USE A LEFT FUNCTION AS SUGGESTED BY MY FRIENDS HERE)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim wksData As Worksheet
Dim lngLastRow As Long, lngIdx As Long, _
lngDateCol As Long, _
lngReversalCol As Long, _
lngLocationCountryCol As Long, _
lngDestinationCountryCol As Long, _
lngDepartureDateCol As Long, _
lngArrivalDateCol As Long, _
lngNotesCol As Long

Dim varRowNum As Variant
Dim colRowNumsForInsert As Collection
Set colRowNumsForInsert = New Collection

'Set references up-front
lngDateCol = 1
lngLocationCountryCol = 2
lngDepartureDateCol = 3
lngArrivalDateCol = 4
lngDestinationCountryCol = 5
lngNotesCol = 6


Set wksData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
lngLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksData)

'Loop through the data range BACKWARDS, tracking each case where a row will need to be in a collection
With wksData
    For lngIdx = lngLastRow To 2 Step -1

        'If the Notes Column = "INSERT", though, we also need 'to note that row number so we can eventually add a new row there
        If .Cells(lngIdx, lngNotesCol) = "INSERT" Then
            colRowNumsForInsert.Add Item:=lngIdx, Key:=CStr(lngIdx)
        End If

    Next lngIdx


    'Now we just need to add rows where necessary and apply the right values

    'Loop through the row numbers in our collection, which are conveniently in REVERSE order (as adding rows will change the row numbers in the range, making forward looping very difficult)
    For Each varRowNum In colRowNumsForInsert

        'First, insert a new row, shifting everything below it down
        .Range("A" & varRowNum).Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown

        'Write the date (which are the same)
        .Cells(varRowNum + 1, lngDateCol) = .Cells(varRowNum, lngDateCol)

        'Write the new location (which is the new location from the row above)
        .Cells(varRowNum + 1, lngLocationCountryCol) = .Cells(varRowNum, lngDestinationCountryCol)
        .Cells(varRowNum, lngNotesCol) = ""
    Next varRowNum

End With

'Let the user know the script is done
MsgBox "Finished!"

End Sub


'INPUT       : Sheet, the worksheet we'll search to find the last row
'OUTPUT      : Long, the last occupied row
'SPECIAL CASE: if Sheet is empty, return 1

Public Function LastOccupiedRowNum(Sheet As Worksheet) As Long
Dim lng As Long
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet.Cells) <> 0 Then
    With Sheet
        lng = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
    End With
Else
    lng = 1
End If
LastOccupiedRowNum = lng

End Function
```

Comment: What have you tried / researched so far, and what exactly isn't working? [Edit] your post to show your existing code, and the error message(s) you are receiving.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have not found anything in particular, other than vba to copy data from Sheet1 to Sheet2 and then insert rows based on values in particular cell. What I am not able to find is a code that would read the criteria I mentioned above - Read a text format column C and text format column D and if the date is same, insert a row. If the date is now same, then do not insert row, follow the sequence.

Comment: Thing is, you'll get much better support and advice if you a) TRY, and b) SHARE what you have tried. At the moment, it looks like you just want somebody to write code for you... and that's not what this site is for.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood well what you need, this should work:

```
Sub Santhosh()
    Dim lastRow, i As Long

    Sheets(2).Range("A1:E1").Value = Sheets(1).Range("A1:E1").Value

    lastRow = Sheets(1).Cells(Sheets(1).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        If Left(Sheets(1).Range("C" & i).Value, 11) = Left(Sheets(1).Range("D" & i).Value, 11) Then
            Sheets(2).Range("A" & i).Value = Sheets(1).Range("A" & i).Value
            Sheets(2).Range("B" & i).Value = Sheets(1).Range("E" & i).Value
        Else
            Sheets(2).Range("A" & i & ":E" & i).Value = Sheets(1).Range("A" & i & ":E" & i).Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Stefano, thanks for your reply and I believe I am going in the right direction. By using the condition, a new row was not inserted. In case I was not clear earlier, I am adding the tasks again. 

Step 1 - Copy data from Sheet1 to Sheet2 (your code works perfect)
Step 2 - If Column C Departure Date and Column D Arrival Date is on the same day, then insert a new row after the date where the condition is met. The new row will have the same date as above and the new location country from Column E. For the dates where the conditions are not met, retain the same date and same country.

Comment: In other words, the edits that may be required would be 1. Insert a row if the criteria is met on a particular date and add new location (column E value) to the new row and 2. Any date that does not meet the criteria should retain the same location.

Comment: I have edited my original question with a code I was able to create.